# Method onNewIntent not executing after destroying Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have developed an app to upload images to a server(like facebook Image Upload),I have used a Background Service to upload Image,when upload starts ,a notification progress will be displayed,When user cliks on the notification,I want to show a popup window whether to Cancel or continue upload,So I have written onNewIntent method in an activity,when user clicks on the notification ,that activity(Say activity ImageViewActivity) will be started and I want to show the popup.But the onNewIntent method is not executing instead the onCreate method of ImageViewActivity is executed.Why this happened??, the launch mode of that activity is SingleTop.Can anybody help me??

Notification and Pending Intent in MyService.java

```
  private void startNotification() {


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    CharSequence notiText = "Your notification from the service";
    long meow = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, notiText, meow);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Your notification";
    CharSequence contentText = "Some data has arrived!";

    //PENDING INTENT
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ImageViewActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

    int SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED = 1;
    notificationManager.notify(SERVER_DATA_RECEIVED, notification);


    }
```

onNewIntent Method in ImageViewActivity.java

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   super.onNewIntent(intent);
   initiatePopupWindow();
      }
```

Here I am calling initiatePopupWindow() Method.

```
  public void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ImageViewActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupmenu, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        // pwindo.setFocusable(true);
        pwindo.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        //  pwindo.showAsDropDown();
        Button btnStopUpload = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        btnStopUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
              //  mNotifyManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
                //  mTask.cancel(true);
                Log.e(TAG, "Notification Cancelled ");
                // mTask.cancel(true);
              /*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Upload Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                Intent i=new Intent(ImageViewActivity.this,MyService.class);
                //stopService(i);
                ImageViewActivity.this.stopService(i);
                ImageViewActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });


        Button btnCancelPopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);

        btnCancelPopup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                pwindo.dismiss();

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "POPUP Rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("COOKBOOK", "I got an error", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)' on a null object reference
        at project1.me.com.cookbookintent.ImageViewActivity.initiatePopupWindow(ImageViewActivity.java:266)
        at project1.me.com.cookbookintent.ImageViewActivity.onCreate(ImageViewActivity.java:90)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

OnCreate ()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view);

    Log.i(TAG, "Activity created");

    try{
    Intent intent = getIntent();

  if (intent.getBooleanExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION",false)) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
              "Reject", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      initiatePopupWindow();
  }

  }
  // int value= intent.getExtras().getInt("FROM_NOTIFICATION");
     // if(value==2){


  catch (Exception e){

      Log.i(TAG, "Rejected");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
              "Reject", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // creating connection detector class instance
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    //Image from sdcard
    try {
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        picturePath = intent1.getExtras().getString("key");
        state = intent1.getExtras().getInt("first_state");
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        decodeFile(picturePath);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Gallery State" + picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "pic not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    ///Camera Image
    try {
        if (picturePath == null) {
            Intent camIntent = getIntent();
            picturePath= camIntent.getExtras().getString("filePath");
            state = camIntent.getExtras().getInt("first_state");
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            decodeFile(picturePath);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PATH" + picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            bitmap = ShrinkBitmap(picturePath, 300, 300);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Please select image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    uploadPicture();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what is expected: if the Activity has not been destroyed, you get the Intent in your onNewIntent, otherwise a new Activity will be created and you have to handle the Intent inside the onCreate. A simple snippet of code to create a PopupWindow:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View root = findViewById(R.id.parentView);
    root.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_view, null, false);
            PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, 300, 300, true);
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.test), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

where R.id.parentView is one of the View of your Activity and R.layout.popup_view is your PopupWindow layout.

Comment: OK,So can you help,how can I handle this issue?,I want to show the popup menu when user clicks on the notification.How to do that?Thanks..

Comment: Check the Intent inside the onCreate too. If it looks like the Intent that you provide with the Notification call the `initiatePopupWindow();`; for example you can add a boolean to your Intent `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ImageViewActivity.class); notificationIntent.putExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION", true);` and then inside the onCreate() `Intent intent = getIntent(); if (intent.getBooleanExtra("FROM_NOTIFICATION", false)) { initiatePopupWindow(); }`

Comment: That's cool !!!...Hai Thanks for this simple solution..but still, initiatePopupWindow();  method is not executing.Any other reason??Please Help me if you can.Thank you

Comment: Put a log inside the onCreate(). At least that method is executed?

Comment: Can you check my edit??, I think the problem is with my method,because the Toast is printed inside if condition except initiatepopup() method

Comment: How do you get the inflater? It is null!

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) ImageViewActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: Are you getting the inflater before calling the initiatePopupWindow() ?

Comment: The above code is ,inside initiatePopupWindow()  method

Comment: I am sory to disturbing you..I am a beginer..please help me if you can

Comment: In the code you posted there's no reference to inflater, update it. Otherwise I cannot understand where's is the mistake. Post the onCreate of your Activity too :)

Comment: please see my edited code( initiatePopupWindow() method and onCreate method) :).Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here is not really true.  onNewIntent will be called if the activity is already on the tasklist.  Regardless if it's been destroyed or not.

So in the case of low memory you'll see both onCreate then onNewIntent get called.

If you finish() an activity, so it's no longer on your task list or if the activity is a just getting added to the task list onNewIntent will not be called.